# save web page with all the related content

Tags: browser, firefox-extensions, web-crawler

I am trying to figure how I can save a webpage with all the related files, for example : http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/xsd/

I want to save all the files in the directory kinda like a crawler but more limited and if possible in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weirdly enough the answer was deleted somehow.

here is the answer:

> wget -r -l2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/xsd

or

> wget -r -np http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/xsd

see https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html

> ‘-np’ ‘--no-parent’ ‘no_parent = on’
>
> ```
> The simplest, and often very useful way of limiting directories is disallowing retrieval of the links that refer to the hierarchy above
> ```
>
> than the beginning directory, i.e. disallowing ascent to the parent
>   directory/directories.
>
> ```
> The ‘--no-parent’ option (short ‘-np’) is useful in this case. Using it guarantees that you will never leave the existing hierarchy.
> ```
>
> Supposing you issue Wget with:
>
> ```
> wget -r --no-parent http://somehost/~luzer/my-archive/
>
> You may rest assured that none of the references to /~his-girls-homepage/ or /~luzer/all-my-mpegs/ will be followed. Only
> ```
>
> the archive you are interested in will be downloaded. Essentially,
>   ‘--no-parent’ is similar to ‘-I/~luzer/my-archive’, only it handles
>   redirections in a more intelligent fashion.
>
> ```
> Note that, for HTTP (and HTTPS), the trailing slash is very important to ‘--no-parent’. HTTP has no concept of a “directory”—Wget
> ```
>
> relies on you to indicate what’s a directory and what isn’t. In
>   ‘http://foo/bar/’, Wget will consider ‘bar’ to be a directory, while
>   in ‘http://foo/bar’ (no trailing slash), ‘bar’ will be considered a
>   filename (so ‘--no-parent’ would be meaningless, as its parent is
>   ‘/’).